# Search and replace inside a function with regex and sublime text

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext3

Is there a way to use regex locating the second input (after comma) inside a php function and and use replace to remove it?

I would like to use this in sublime text to remove an input field inside a function that is used across many pages.

I want this function:

```
LoggFor ($brukerid, $dato, $sysreg, $dat_1 = '', $dat_2 = '', $dat_3 = '', $dat_4 = '', $dat_5 = '', $dat_6 = '', $dat_7 = '')
```

To be replaced with:

```
LoggFor ($brukerid, $sysreg, $dat_1 = '', $dat_2 = '', $dat_3 = '', $dat_4 = '', $dat_5 = '', $dat_6 = '', $dat_7 = '')
```

The problem is that the input across many different pages is not as mentioned above. In other words, I want to remove 2nd input from all functions regardless of variable name.

Screenshot from Sublime Text:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
LoggFor\s*\([^),]*\K,\s*[^,)]*
```

Replace with an empty string.

**Details**

- `LoggFor` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^),]*` - zero or more chars other than `)` and `,`
- `\K` - match reset operator (all text matched up to this place is omitted from the match and thus, it will remain)
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[^,)]*` - zero or more chars other than `)` and `,`

See the screenshot with settings:

[image]